# How can I embed HTML5 Video into a webview

Tags: android, html, video

I have seen instances of this question asked before, but I either couldn't get them to work or didnt understand them..

I have made sure to set my webview to WebChromeClient and enable hardware scceleration in the manifest file.  I am sending the compiled application to a Samsung Galaxy Tab  GT-P1000.  The result is that the video element loads but the file does not play.  The html file runs as exptected in chrome on my PC.

I don't have a lot of experience with ADT so if you could try to be as verbose as possible with your replies that would be great!

Here is my html code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="video">
            <video id="vid" height="240" width="360" preload controls>
                <source src="ljmuvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        </div>
        <script>
            var video = document.getElementById('vid');
            video.addEventListener('click',function(){
            video.play();
            },false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.ljmu.sltwebview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html5vid.html");
        mywebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mywebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ljmu.sltwebview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ljmu.sltwebview.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: does it work if you load from a url not local storage - will at least help narrow down if the problem is the webview setup for the video, or dealing with local assets. Guess I should try tweaking this [https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414] to use a local asset

Comment: okay, I'm stumped. can't get it to play when the asset is in the assets folder. read some comments about compression being a problem but can't find an easy way around that. suspect you may have to copy the video to the SD card before playing

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me, what would be the explicit path that I would have to use to point to the SD card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it won't let you play a movie from the Assets folder you will need to copy the video (and for convenience other assets) to the SDcard.

This post has a great sample to do this [How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard) though you will need to add code to create the output directory (also from the comments there). You might also want to check if the files exist and avoid copying them when you don't need to

Once you have moved the HTML page you can reference it in the webview via file:///sdcard/{myapp}/default.html and then paths to assets will be relative to the document

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work I also tried hosting the video on a remote server and changing the url in the html file and that didnt work either.

Comment: have you enabled hardware acceleration in the manifest? for a webview to play video that seems to be key - see sample at gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414

Comment: Yep, as above android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: Can you host the video somewhere for us to test - it may be an encoding issue - or try with a know good test video. Also do you see any output at all in logcat from ADT?

Comment: I've tested the video in an android video player if thats any good to you on an android galaxy tablet.  I haven't tried setting up logcat i'll give that a go.

Comment: would need to test the video in the same way ... sometimes the player app may be able to handle different encodings (eg I have video that plays fine in VLC or similar, but won't play in a webview)

Comment: This was an encoding issue, re-encoded to MP4 and works fine.

Comment: fantastic news - would be great to know what profile worked for you (vs what didn't) in case others are looking (so many subtle device variants it drives folks mad!)